# Can we use reference transaction in Paypal REST API?

Tags: api, paypal

Is there a way to implement reference transaction in paypal rest api like in paypal classic api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that the REST API supports this at this time. You can still use Classic to get the same result if necessary. They use the same authentication tokens.