# Is there any alternative for Reference Transaction in Paypal REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

After some time of researching and exploring the Paypal REST API documentation, I've found that currently reference transaction is available only in Paypal Classic API but not in Paypal REST API as stated [in this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473877/can-we-use-reference-transaction-in-paypal-rest-api) so I'm trying to find an alternative to bill users with different amounts every month.

Integrated Paypal REST API in my Rails 4 application. I'm trying to create agreements with auto-billing plans without charging real amount, and I planned to use `set-balance` to charge the remaining amounts and bill the users with outstanding amount. Eventually I've searched through the methods in paypal-sdk-rest but there's no method for me to set an outstanding balance on the agreement object.

And now I'm in stuck. Is there a Ruby method call to set and bill the outstanding balance to the agreements, or perhaps another way of charging users with different amounts every month?

A way I'd think of is to send invoices to users manually by using the Invoice object in REST API, but I prefer to bill users using agreements instead. Using Classic API might be the best option in this case but REST is still a better choice for future.

Hope to get reference transaction works in REST API very soon.

Plan:

```
   plan = Paypal::Plan.new({
    name: "Test Plan",
    description: "Test recurring plan",
    type: "infinite",
      payment_definitions: [{
        name:"Free Trial",
        type:"TRIAL",
        frequency:"MONTH",
        frequency_interval:"1",
        amount: { 
          value: "0.00",
          currency: "USD"
        },
        cycles: "1"
      },
      {
        name:"Standard Package",
        type:"REGULAR",
        frequency:"MONTH",
        frequency_interval:"1",
        amount: { 
          value: "0.01",
          currency: "USD"
        },
        cycles: "11"
      }],
    merchant_preferences: {
      setup_fee: {
          value: "0",
          currency: "USD"
      },
      auto_bill_amount: "YES",
      return_url: return_url,
      cancel_url: cancel_url,
    }
  })
```

Agreement:

```
  agreement = Paypal::Agreement.new({
    name: "Monthly billing",
    description: "Billing Agreement",
    start_date: (Date.today+ 1.month).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"),
    payer: {
      payment_method: "paypal",
    },
    plan: {
      id: Settings.plan_id
  }})
```

Comment: what about billing agreement in REST API : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements

and VAULT in rest API.

Comment: The code provided above is billing agreement.

Comment: Why not just use the Classic API instead?  I still prefer it over REST for reasons such as this.  The Classic API is much more mature and feature packed than REST, and it's probably going to take them a while to get REST caught up (if it ever does).